# UIScrollview zoom is making UIScrollview's subview Pan

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I have some troubles with my `UIScrollView`. So here's the situation:
I have a `UIScrollView` with few small `UIView` inside.
`UIView` have a Pan event to move them inside the scrollview. But When I zoom my scrollview and one of my finger is on a `UIview` that make a pan begin and my `UIScrollView` is not zooming (and the `UIview` is moving).

I tried to set the `MaximumNumberOfTouches` of the pan but that doesn't work. I think it's because the second touch is outside the view.
Do you have any idea how to make it work?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol** in your View Controller, so that you can use the `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:` method and return `true` when needed. You can form a restrictive predicate by comparing the first and second parameters with, respectively, your Pan Gesture Recognizer and the Scroll View's Pinch Gesture Recognizer:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return gestureRecognizer == myPanGestureRecognizer && otherGestureRecognizer == scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer
}
```

That way, the latter will wait until the Scroll View's Gesture Recognizer fails before transitioning to state `.Recognized`. More information can be found in [Apple Gesture Recognizer Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW24).

Do not forget to set your Pan Gesture Recognizer's delegate property to `self` :

```
myPanGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I set the delegate for the pan and it return false for zooming pinch of the scrollview. But now the pan never start event if we don't pinch. Do you have any idea what I missed?

Comment: Mmmm… I just tried it, and even without adding the delegate protocol method above, everything seems to work out-of-the-box. Are you sure that you correctly set your scroll view's `minimumZoomScale` and `maximumZoomScale`?